# In a csv file get all values of rows and columns between 2 specific words say start and stop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with time,event and acceleration values(x,y,z) as columns and I want to fetch only the values between the event values start and stop(where in event column there are various words like start stop motion location). I have done using data frame in pandas but I get values of start and stop instead of all the values in between them.

Csv file:

```
 time   event   earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y earthAcceleration.z

2017-11-22T09:20:13.944 motion  -0.006380   -0.001029   -0.010781

2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 start 

2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion  0.008521    -0.008223   0.022574

2017-11-22T09:20:13.974 stop    

2017-11-22T09:20:13.984 motion  0.016283    0.003181    0.006969
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('nehi.csv')
df = df[df['event'].between('start', 'stop', inclusive=True)]
df
```

My output is: values where the words = start and stop

```
time    event   earthAccelerationx earthAccelerationy earthAccelerationz

2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 start   NaN NaN NaN

2017-11-22T09:20:13.974 stop    NaN NaN NaN
```

Also tried

```
start= event[(event['event']=='start') & (event['event']=='stop')]
start.head()
```

But gives empty values

Desired output is: Values of time and acceleration between the words start and stop.

```
time       event    earthAccelerationx  earthAccelerationy earthAccelerationz

2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion  0.008521    -0.008223   0.022574
```

Goal: To extract all column and row values between 2 keywords in column named events.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example of the csv data = ([mcve])

Comment: @wwii I did edit now, have a look!

Comment: how are you getting the value of `0.014740` in your desired outcome? is there any aggregating going on?

Comment: @MattR that is just the value in the column of acceleration, so basically desired outcome is getting all values of all columns between the word start and stop

Comment: I don't see `0.014740` in your sample data here :/

Comment: @MattR now you can? sorry I just put dummy values so you got confused sorry a bout that, now you can undrestand I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
start_index = df[df['event'].str.contains('start')].index[0] + 1
stop_index = df[df['event'].str.contains('stop')].index[0] - 1
new_df = df.loc[start_index:stop_index, :]


    time                    event   earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y earthAcceleration.z
2   2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion  0.008521            -0.008223   0.022574
```

EDIT: This will give you a list of dataframes with with rows between each start and stop

```
start_index = df[df['event'].str.contains('start')].index
stop_index = df[df['event'].str.contains('stop')].index
l_dfs = []
for i in range(len(start_index)):
    l_dfs.append(df.loc[start_index[i]+1:stop_index[i]-1, :])
```

Comment: Thats actually perfect. Thanks a ton! But there are several start and stop in the file, how do I separate them individual suppose there are 5-6 sets of start and stop. So while parsing when start comes it writes into a file/df and when stop comes just exit, so the df consists of just one set of start stop values.

Comment: Do you want to capture all start and stop as this solution will capture data between first start and stop

Comment: Oh so this is the data between the first start and first stop? No i want to capture between all start and stop so there will be like 5-6 new df/file with the data between start and stop.

Comment: Okay that I understood, but Cant I save or write different start stop set in diff df or file? Now I have all dfs in one df how will I extract into different df?

Comment: @NehiPatel, l_df[0] is your first dataframe and so on

Comment: WOW thanks a lot, you're truly an expert haha. I saw your profile you are a data analyst, I want to go on the same career path as well. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Hey I had one  more question on this, what if I want to make the df on loop? So now I know that there are 5 sets of start stop so I just store them differently, but when it is unknown how can i create a loop such that it automatically stores each set in a new df.

Comment: This is already doing it automatically. start_index is capturing indices of all the rows with start and same with stop. After that the loop is simply taking the first start and first stop and returning dataframe with all the data between the two and it continues till it goes upto the end of start_index

Answer (score 0):

I use 'hello' and 'world' how keywords.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('two.txt', header=None, delimiter="hello", engine='python')
df2 = df.loc[:, 1]
values = []

for row in df2:
    print (row.index('world'))
    values.append(row[:row.index('world')])

print(values)
```

Comment: In this are you extracting between column values hello and world?

Comment: Not between columns, between strings, if values are in differents columns, also work.

Answer (score 0):

You could process the file first to extract the data you want.  This checks for the keywords and uses a flag to toggle keeping or disregarding the data.

csv file:

```
import io

s = ''' time   event   earthAcceleration.x earthAcceleration.y earthAcceleration.z
2017-11-22T09:20:13.944 motion  -0.006380   -0.001029   -0.010781
2017-11-22T09:20:13.954 start 
2017-11-22T09:20:13.964 motion  0.008521    -0.008223   0.022574
2017-11-22T09:20:13.974 stop    
2017-11-22T09:20:13.984 motion  0.016283    0.003181    0.006969
'''
#Python 2.7
f = io.BytesIO(s)
#Python 3.6
#f = io.StringIO(s)
```

Preprocess:

```
flag = False
data = []
header = f.next()
#or
#header = f.readline()
header = header.split()
for line in f:
   line = line.split()
   #print(line)
   if line[1] == 'start':
      flag = True
      continue
   elif line[1] == 'stop':
      flag = False
      continue
   if flag:
      data.append(line)
      #print(line)
```

---

Working with an actual file, use a context manager while processing.

```
flag = False
data = []
with open('nehi.txt') as f:
   header = next(f)
   header = header.split()
   for line in f:
      line = line.split()
      #print(line)
      if line[1] == 'start':
         flag = True
         continue
      elif line[1] == 'stop':
         flag = False
         continue
      if flag:
         data.append(line)
         #print(line)
```

---

Then you could feed `data` and `header` to pandas if you need a DataFrame.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=data, columns = header)
```

Comment: import io
with open ('nehi.csv','r') as s:
    s = f = io.BytesIO(s)
    flag = False
data = []
header = f.next()
header = header.split()
for line in f:
    line = line.split()
   #print(line)
    if line[1] == 'start':
            flag = True
            continue
    elif line[1] == 'stop':
            flag = False
            continue
    if flag:
              data.append(line)
      #print(line)

Comment: ERROR IN THE ABOVE CODE:  bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'

Comment: Can you show me the file in the edit rather than the string? because i will b e parsing a csv file

Comment: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next' NEW ERROR